# Error apa.cbx 'Missing \begin{document}. \DeclareDelimAlias[np'

Tags: biblatex, errors, citing, biber, apa-style

I read a few other questions, but for this problem, I didn't find a solution. 
Could you maybe help me?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=apa,
%style=apa, natbib=true,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{X}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It says:
"Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'."
"Package biblatex Info: Delimiter '[' in context '' already defined, overwriting"
The error message: apa.cbx 'Missing \begin{document}. \DeclareDelimAlias[np'

Comment: This looks like your `biblatex-apa` version is too new for you `biblatex` version. Make sure that your system is completely up to date. (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864 if you are using multi-user MikTeX setup, run the update in Admin and User mode)

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you won't need `\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}` with a current `biblatex-apa` version.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP solved their problem by updating their distribution.